# How pass a variable from view to controller in Laravel without using the URL or forms

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-8

What if I want to pass a variable like $k =1 (but the value of $K changes because it's a for loop counter) from view as an argument in a function in the controller without using the URL.
The status column is represented in the database table "parcel" from 0-2. For example, in the foreach loop if the value of $k =0 then the controller function gets the value of $k, counts the number of times 0 appears in the database (status) using the count() method, then returns the value of count to the View.

**View**

```
@php
$status_arr = array("Item Accepted by Courier","Collected","Shipped");
@endphp

@foreach($status_arr as $k =>$v)
<!-- Parcel stages -->
<div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
    <div class="card border-left-warning shadow h-100 py-2">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row no-gutters align-items-center">
                <div class="col mr-2">
                    <div class="text-xs font-weight-bold text-warning 
                        text-uppercase mb-1">
                        {{$v}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="h5 mb-0 font-weight-bold text-gray-800">
                        {{$statuses}}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-auto">
                    <i class="fas fa-bicycle fa-2x text-gray-300"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

**Controller**

```
function total_parcels()
{
    $status = DB::table('parcels')
        ->where('status', '=', $k)
        ->count();

    return view('dashboard', ['statuses' => $status]);
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('dashboard', [DashboardController::class, 'total_parcels']);
```

Comment: use ajax request when variable change call api and pass the value

Comment: You can't pass a variable to the Controller, because the controller code runs before the view. You can however use a component to load a part of the view, where you can run code like in a controller

Comment: So, it is not possible to call the function in view?

Comment: You can create a helper function, you can create a component, you can use Ajax, but should not call a controller function from the view. Thats just not how MVC works.

Comment: With XMLHttpRequest you can send data from client / View data .

Comment: @MaikLowrey how do I do that?

Comment: @Lateef26 I don't know your application. How is the counter triggered, what you want create  etc. I need more details.

Comment: I don't really understand your question.

Comment: @MaikLowrey I want to loop through the status of delivery from the database, using the foreach loop.  The status column is represented in the database table parcel from 0-2. For example, if the value of $k =0 then the controller function counts the number of times 0 appears in the database (status) using the count() method, then returns the value of count to the View.

Comment: so why don't you get all parcels in the database in your controller? That way you get a collection in your view, on that collection you can filter, and count. I would also remove the `@php` and pass the `$status_arr` in the controller to the view. that would be a lot cleaner.

Comment: You can even group by status and select the count in one query.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you calculate statuses and their counts in the controller. Then pass the prepared data to the view for just "displaying" it?

I think you didn't have to pass data from view to controller.